# The dimension of algebraic set $\{ F(x_1y_1, ..., x_my_m) = 0 \}$ compared to the dimension of $\{ F(x_1, ..., x_m) = 0 \}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

Let $F_i$ be homogeneous forms with $\mathbb{C}$ coefficients in $n$ variables for each $i$.
Let
$$
T_2 = \{ (\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) \in  \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^{2n} :  F_i(x_1y_1, ..., x_n y_n) =0, 1 \leq i \leq s \}
$$
and
$$
T_1 = \{ \mathbf{x} \in  \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^{n} :  F_i(x_1, ..., x_n) =0, 1 \leq i \leq s \}. 
$$
I am trying to prove that
$$
\dim T_2 \leq n + \dim T_1. 
$$
This is simple enough to do if $T_1$ only contains zero. I feel like there is a simple way to prove this that I don't see. Any comments and suggestions are appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Let $pr_y:T_2\to \mathbb{C}^n$ be the projection on the $y$ coordinates. Then $pr_y^{-1}((\mathbb{C}^*)^n)$, a dense open of $T_2$, is isomorphic to $T_1\times (\mathbb{C}^*)^n$.

Comment: how do we know that $pr^{-1}((\mathbb{C}^*)^n)$ is a dense open subset of $T_2$? Does this hold even when $T_2$ is not irreducible?

Comment: You're right: $pr_y^{-1}((\mathbb{C}^*)^n)$ is not dense in $T_2$ in general (e.g. if $T_1=V(F_1)$ where $F_1=x_1x_2$). I'll write an answer for the more general case when I have more time.

Comment: good to know, thank you!